# How to print trace of a tree node in Antlr4

Tags: java, python, antlr4

I am trying to build a method for searching in AST. This method will take a string and find the tree nodes which include that string.
But I have many questions in my mind.

For example:

-Should I use visitors or listeners?

-Should I fill all listener methods or can I handle with one or a few listener methods?

-...

To illustrate my code parsed antlr4 is that:

```
public class HelloWorld {   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
}
```

And my method searching for "Hello" word.
The result must be something like that:

**class HelloWorld, method main, first line**

or

**class HelloWorld, method main, method println, parameter one**

I have tried but none of my ways worked.
Do you have any idea or code example?

I use antlr4 package. Java or Python example would be perfect for me.

Comment: You ought to remove the tag "Python".

Comment: Antlr4 package is available for Python and my main purpose is using antlr in Python. Then, an  example Python code recommendations would be perfect for me. Thanks for your suggestion but I am adding Python tag again and a sentence in the question.

Comment: I tried a new way of following code rows. Control flow diagrams are enough for my purpose for now. And I use listener methods for building a control flow diagram of a code in a new grammar written by myself using antlr4. The code is in [here](https://github.com/hacetin/anltr4_java)